# Install Zeppelin in yarn cluster

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, apache-zeppelin

I am trying [to install apache zeppelin in yarn cluster](https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.5.5-incubating/install/yarn_install.html).

After installing and visiting `http://localhost:8080`, zeppelin is launching but it's asking me to log in. How I register or login? 
It works well in my mac system, and it does not prompt a login. But in the cluster it prompts login.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Without actually trying it, I would guess some user that is on that linux box.

Comment: Seems something else is running in the 8080 port. Can you stop the service and access the same url.

Comment: Thanks for a reply, I have changed zeppelin port 8080 to 9000 but it is not working.